# How to get tensors (not variables) from tf estimator?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I'm using tf estimator api to train a LSTM model with attention. I defined the `model_fn` as follows. Once the model is trained, I want to get the tensor "attention_a". It is not a variable. So, I cannot get it using `get_variable_value()`. I tried to use `tf.summary.tensor_summary("alpha", a)`. But the tensor cannot be found in TensorBoard.

Any ideas how I can retrieve the tensor after training?

```
def bilstm_fn(features, labels, mode, params):
    ...
    # Attention
    with tf.variable_scope("Attention", reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE):
        W = tf.get_variable("W", [n_units*2, attn_size])
        b = tf.get_variable("b", [attn_size])
        e = tf.tanh(tf.tensordot(dropout1, W, axes=1) + b)
        a = tf.nn.softmax(e, name="attention_a")
        r = tf.multiply(a, dropout1)
    ...
    if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.TRAIN:
        optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer()
        train_op = optimizer.minimize(loss=loss, 
            global_step=tf.train.get_global_step())
        return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode=mode, loss=loss, 
            train_op=train_op)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use   tf.get_tensor_by_name()  to get the one you want.

Comment: Thanks. It seems that in the current TF version, it is `tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name`. I also figured that is is better to pass the tensor with the prediction outputs.